# Laravel "where" query with eager loading and relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently trying to do a custom forum software for a client, and I'm using the laravel framework.
The "board" contains "discussions" that haveMany "comments". Each discussion belongsTo a "category".

What I'm trying to do now, is creating an overview by category. Categories are predefined (like "news", "internal", "project" ...) and discussions *can* be assigned to them (the category is nullable).

The controller method to get the discussions by category, searching by the url-slug looks as follows:

```
return View::make('pages.board.overview', [
    'discussions', DiscussionCategory::where('slug', $slug)->discussions()->paginate(25)
]);
```

Except, that it doesn't work. I would like to retrieve all discussions (with their author, normally I would have used `::with('author')`, but where do add that in this case?) that have the specified category, paginated by 25 items.

How do I build a query that does that? Is it even possible to do it in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
DiscussionCategory::where('slug', $slug)->with('discussions.author')->paginate(25)
```

Set foreign key on the relation:

```
// Discussion model, the same applies to the Category model
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Umc\Models\DiscussionCategory', 'category_id');
}
```

Paginating discussions:

```
$category = DiscussionCategory::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$discussions = $category->discussions()->paginate(25);
$discussions->load('author'); // eager load authors on the collection
```

Comment: Wow, okay... that almost works. I just got this error though: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'board_discussions.discussion_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `board_discussions` where `board_discussions`.`deleted_at` is null and `board_discussions`.`discussion_category_id` in (1))`

Comment: Then you relationships are not setup correctly. Show the discussion model please.

Comment: Okay, here is the Discussion model: http://hastebin.com/onaxosurel.php, and here is the category model: http://hastebin.com/sunegokiqi.php

Comment: I also have a few relationship issues as well - if we can fix it in this issue i don't need to open a new one ;)

Comment: OK so it seems FK on discussion table is category_id, while Eloquent looks for default which is related_class_id, because you didn't specify custom key. Check my edit in a sec

Comment: Somehow that didn't seem to work... The query returns a collection of paginated categories, and not the discussions itself. It also doesn't fill in the eager loading things ($category->discussion returns null).

Comment: Pagination will work on categories here, that's true. If you want to paginate the discussions then it will be different query